# Преобразование строкового массива после split()

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки

Исходные данные:

```
str="[[a,b] , [c,d] , [e,f]]";
arr=str.split(' , '); 
//arr выглядит так["[a,b]", "[c,d]", "[e,f]"]
```

как сделать, чтобы arr стал вот таким:

```
[[a,b], [c,d], [e,f]]
```

Comment: именно `[[a,b], [c,d], [e,f]]` или все же `[["a","b"],["c","d"],["e","f"]]` ?

Comment: именно [[a,b], [c,d], [e,f]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это массив, в котором содержаться массивы. Следовательно, это валидный `JSON`, который мы можем парсить.

```js
var str = "[[1,2] , [3,4] , [5,6]]";

var res = JSON.parse(str);

console.log(res);

console.log(res[0][1]);
```

Comment: занятно, это было моей первой мыслью. однако если вместо цифр будут буквы, будет [ошибка](http://jsfiddle.net/06ovnh8u/)

Comment: @Alex Конечно будет ошибка. Но ведь вместо букв у вас **[a,b] , [c,d]... это не буквы, это любые значения. (в моем случае это географические координаты)**. Пожалуйста, задавайте вопрос с актуальными данными, а не сферическими в вакууме.

Comment: @Следовательно, это валидный JSON, который мы можем парсить.@ Точно!!!!! Спасибо большое.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko это не мой вопрос. а так да, с цифрами это json)

Comment: @Alex извините, не обратил внимания, что вы не ТС)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let str = "[[a,b] , [c,d] , [e,f]]";
//let str2_ar = str.replace(/[^a-z,]/g, '').split(',');
//ниже удаляем [[,]],]пробел,пробел[ и создаем массив
let str2_ar = str.replace(/(\[\[)|(\]\])|(\]\s)|(\s\[)/g, '').split(',');
let str3_ar = [];
for (let a = 0; a < str2_ar.length; a++) {
  str3_ar.push([str2_ar[a], str2_ar[a + 1]]);
  a = a + 1;
}
console.log(str3_ar);
```

Comment: Поправка: [a,b] , [c,d]... это не буквы, это любые значения. (в моем случае это географические координаты)

Comment: @ColdPol ответ обновлен